# Sortable.js with Vue 2.0 sorts incorrectly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, rubaxa-sortable

I am using Sortable.js and Vue.js. The goal is to sort items and keep data updated.

It worked well with Vue 1.x, but after update to 2.0 sorting became incorrect. Array still properly updates, but items in DOM are in the wrong places.

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#sort',
  data: function() {
    return {
      items: [
        "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image1",
        "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image2",
        "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image3",
        "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image4"
      ],  
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(function () {
      Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable'), {
        animation: 200,
        onUpdate: this.reorder.bind(this),
      });
    })
  },
  methods: {
    reorder: function(event) {
        var oldIndex = event.oldIndex,
            newIndex = event.newIndex;
        this.items.splice(newIndex, 0, this.items.splice(oldIndex, 1)[0]);

    } 
   }
});
```

jsFiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/4bvtofdd/4/

Can someone help me?

Comment: I'm afraid sortable is not compatible right now with vue 2.0 due to the virtual dom. Both seem to be have an incompatibility when the DOM is modified.The only possible "patch" I see is to use 2 arrays, 1 for painting and the other to keep track of changes

Comment: Oh. Guess I have to use another plugin then :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it happens, Sortable keeps track of the order in `sortable.toArray()`, so it's pretty easy to make a computed that will give you the items in sorted order, while the original item list is unchanged.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: '#sort',
  data: {
    items: [
      "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image1",
      "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image2",
      "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image3",
      "http://placehold.it/200X300?text=image4"
    ],
    order: null
  },
  computed: {
    sortedItems: function() {
      if (!this.order) {
       return this.items;
      }
      return this.order.map((i) => this.items[i]);
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      const sortable = Sortable.create(document.getElementById('sortable'), {
        animation: 200,
        onUpdate: () => { this.order = sortable.toArray(); }
      });
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Sortable/1.4.2/Sortable.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@2.0.1/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id='app'></div>
<template id="sort">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row sort-wrap" id="sortable">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3 thumbnail" v-for="(item, index) in items" :data-id="index">
        <img v-bind:src="item" alt="" class="img-responsive">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div v-for="item in sortedItems">
    {{item}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar problem today.

Add :key value to make sure Vue rerenders elements in correct order after Sortable changes the items order

```
<div v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <!-- content -->
</div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you aren't using a prop, or you won't be able to sort. If you are using a prop, assign the prop data to a data attribute and use the data attribute instead.